# Rails : NoMethodError (undefined method `submitting' for []:Array)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `submitting' for []:Array):
   haml (2.2.0) lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:19:in `process_without_compass'
   compass (0.8.17) lib/compass/app_integration/rails/action_controller.rb:7:in `process'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.3.6/lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27:in `call'
```

getting error like this 
Should any one have any idea about that?

Comment: @sachinrathore11 would you please provide us with a chunk of your code so that it would be a little easier to analyze the problem

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say exactly without seeing your code, but it seems like you try to access a method on an array instead of a model object or something. Are you passing an array of objects to a view instead of only one object?